# API JSON to CSV or Google Sheets

Tags: json, csv, sorting, google-sheets

I want to sort the values in csv (or google sheet)with an API. But my knowledge of JSON=0. I'm not sure how to retrieve the right data.
Also i dont know how to sort JSON (xD)

```
import json
import requests
import csv

api_key = "https://api.blablablbla"

r = requests.get('https://api.blablablbla')
packages_json = r.json()
```

The sorting should by header name: projectnumber, project name etc. and the rows should be the "value" corrosponding the header. I feel like the imput of the data is not perfect. The input is as follows(parsed):

```
{
"results": [
{
"submittedAt": 1614950496814,
"values": [
{
"name": "projectnumber?",
"value": "123",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "project name?_",
"value": "Project X",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "email",
"value": "abc@123.com",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "firstname",
"value": "James",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "lastname",
"value": "Bond",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "Are you available?_",
"value": "Maybe later",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "Send reminder?_",
"value": "Yes",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "form filled in by",
"value": "Jimmy",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
}
],
"pageUrl": "https://share.hsforms.com/.........."
},
```

The second 1:

```
{
"submittedAt": 1614943909980,
"values": [
{
"name": "projectnumber?",
"value": "1234",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "project name?",
"value": "XYZ",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "email",
"value": "bca@bobs.nl",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "firstname",
"value": "Jan",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "lastname",
"value": "de Vries",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "Are you available?",
"value": "maybe later",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
},
{
"name": "Send reminder",
"value": "yes",
"objectTypeId": "0-1"
}
],
"pageUrl": "https://share.hsforms.com/........."
},
```

Help!

Comment: This seems to be a python question: How can I sort this structure? It doesn't matter if it came from JSON or another format. (BTW you haven't added the python tag). Also why are you mentioning Google Sheet? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this solution but probably if I knew the context the aswer would be more acurate. In first place you should receive the parameters of where you want to insert the values. For example, you use the google sheet API the json will be something like this:

```
    {
       "connection":{
          "workbookID": "ABC",
          "sheetName": "ABC"
       }
       "values": [
       {
          "name": "column1",
          "values": ["rowA", "rowB", "rowC"]
       },
       {
          "name": "column2",
          "values": ["rowA", "rowB", "rowC"]
       }]
    }
```

In the same way, you can change the connections to get the CSV parameters and parce the values on it.
Then you can read the values as arrays and insert them without complication.